# I can't login to tty2 as root?

Tags: login, tty

I use VM VirtualBox. I use ctl+Alt +F2 to login to tty2.

I enter user : root and my password to login but it shows me "login incorrect"

How can I login as root to tty2

Comment: The root account log-in is disabled in Ubuntu by default. It's possible to enable it but there is very little reason to do so compared to the alternative of using `sudo` & friends. Therefore this question sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root is NOT a user in Ubuntu. So not just you, NOBODY can login with "root" in tty2. Nor tty1, tty3, tty4, tty5 or tty6.

If you need to do administrative tasks use the user and password you set Ubuntu up with. That is your account that you can log in with and use "sudo" with to do admin tasks.

Comment: can you please tell me more about root

Comment: You log in with your own user and do `sudo -i` on commandline to get to root. Mind though: you hardly ever need to use that.

Comment: I agree with the gist of your answer but disagree with one (technical) detail: there *is* a `root` user account in Ubuntu (see the output of `getent passwd root`), however it's impossible to log in as `root` with the default configuration because the account has no password (see the output of `sudo getent shadow root`).

Comment: It seems that in the default configuration the user configured doesn't have 'root' access and can't login via tty2, at least in ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is highly discouraged, you CAN make it so you can login as root. To do this you must

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then enter a password for root (twice to confirm)
After this, you must unlock the root account.

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

This will allow root login. 
To revert your changes you can lock the root account with

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

And that will
Prevent root login. 
As I mentioned this is not good practice by any means. Just as other commenters have said, use `sudo <command>`
For root tasks. Or you can get a root session with

```
sudo -i
```

Or

```
sudo su
```